# Date.parse 2.0 almost understand it

Tags: javascript, date

```
window.onload = init;

function init() {
var button = document.getElementById("addButton");
button.onclick = handleButtonClick;
}

function handleButtonClick(e) {
var textInput = document.getElementById("dateTextInput");
var dateString = textInput.value;
var parsedDate = Date.parse(dateString);
var dateValue = new Date(parsedDate);
var valid = !isNaN(dateValue);

if (!valid) {
    alert("Please enter a valid date");
} else {
    alert(dateValue);
}
e.preventDefault();
}
}
```

It now functions, but not with pressing return(enter).  I have to thank [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete) for writing this where I can understand it.

Comment: just using JavaScript, not using jQuery

Comment: I noticed that. Just pass argument `e` into your function.

Comment: @user2445344: Pressing enter in the input box will `submit` the `<form>`, not click the button. You will need to handle a different event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that `e` is undefined as a parameter to your handler.

```
function handleButtonClick() {
    e.preventDefault(); // e is undefined and this line will not work
}
```

Make sure `e` is a defined parameter:

```
function handleButtonClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // e is now defined and will work as expected
}
```

To get the parsed date, simply use that variable:

```
alert(dateValue);
```

Here's a fiddle which should help clarify this: http://jsfiddle.net/mZ9SQ/

Comment: still not working, this is so annoying, I am not even sure if I need the e.preventDefault.  It was from the last suggestion

Comment: It is working now.  One more small issue.  It will not work when pressing the enter key, just a clicking the enter button. Code is updated

Comment: Thank you Pete.  I'll skip the onKeyPress stuff for later.

Comment: @user2445344: If you change `addButton` to an `<input type="submit" />` **and** add `document.forms[0].submit = handleButtonClick;` to `init()`, it will handle the Enter button as well. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mZ9SQ/1/